# Is there a way to call a javascript function from python function in Odoo

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, odoo, point-of-sale

Here is the issue I have right?

[NOTE] this is on **odoo14**

I have a js file that calls a function in python using rpc and it receives the return object; which is perfect.

> Snippet of the JS function:

```
               this.rpc({
                  model: 'atm.transaction',
                  method: 'do_payment_transaction',
                  args: [customer_id],
                }).then(function (data)
                    {
                    console.log("Response of payment",data)
                });
```

The python function on the other hand initiates a request to a third party API; This third party API does its stuff and calls my route which I created under controllers.

I want my function that is inside my route in the controller to call a js function.[This is my main problem].

*Any insights will be much appreciated.*

Comment: Does this help: [How to Run Javascript from Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-javascript-from-python/).

Comment: Nice @bloodyKnuckles, I will definitely check and see if it works on the framework Odoo uses.

Comment: hey @bloodyKnuckles Your answer seems to technically work on a pure python and js setup but is not best practice on Odoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its totally possible. This is how for example odoo displays channel messages in front end. Its done through longpooling.
Here are the step

1. In your python function, send a notification message

```py
self.env['bus.bus'].sendone('your_channel','your_notification_type',dict_parameters)
```

2. In Javascript implement a notification listener and perform your desired action

```js
    this.call('bus_service', 'onNotification', this, this._onLongpollingNotifications);
    /**
         * @private
         * @param {Object[]} notifications
         * @param {string} [notifications[i].type]
         * @param {string} [notifications[i].payload]
         */
        async _onLongpollingNotifications(notifications) {
// your code processed here
}
```

For more info check here : https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ea481271f8f477d1cdcbb94826111955ed9a6a4f/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py#L750